# Estimation for a SharePoint Portal

Tags: productivity

I am working on SharePoint Project Estimation.

Are there any standard practices for estimation of a SharePoint portal?

Comment: Are you including hardware and software licenses in this as well?

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please [edit]  your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be  closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question  flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See [ask] for general guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

It depends on what you are estimating. Cost? Time? Storage? Availability? Backup and Restore? Development? Maintenance & Support? Growth?

Have a browse on the TechNet website for SharePoint, there are many documents and white papers around the planning of a SharePoint implementation. But the recommended practice is generally: get a Microsoft Partner to help you.